# Automatically uncheck Google Sheets checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I made a Google Sheets for my team mates, each member has its own page where there is displayed a table with the days of the week and times, where the person has to click on the checkbox to indicate he can train that specific day and time.

I wanted to **automatically uncheck all the checkboxes on a condition (day of week)**, but the ways I have tried won't let me modify afterwards the checkbox, I just want to reset it all to false and then let each person click on the checkbox to set them to true.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Sheets doesn't have a direct formula for this purpose. Formulas in Google Sheets are generally designed for calculations and not for making changes to cell values dynamically. So you would have to explore Google App Script for this.